Are geometric series related to ellipses in this particular way?
Consider a point $F$ and a line $l$.
Let the point $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular to $l$ passing through $F$.
Let $E$ be the ellipse with focus $F$, directrix $l$ and eccentricity $r$.
Then $E$ intersects the line $FP$ at two points $A$ and $B$. Assuming $AP > BP$, then $AP/FP = 1/(1 - r)$, which I noticed was awfully reminiscent of the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series.
Is that a coincidence?

I think it is not worth spending time on this issue : please note that all $>0$ real numbers can be written under the form $1/(1-r) $ for some $r$...

This suggests that, starting from point $P$, you can construct point $A$ on the ellipse by moving to $F$, then continuing in the same direction but scaling your step size down by $r$. You can construct $B$ in a similar way, but alternating between forward steps and backwards steps. I assume that this process, starting from different points on $l$ defines all of the points of $E$.

I suspect the angle bisector theorem could be squeezed in somewhere.

I would strongly recommend drawing and uploading a diagram of this.

@JeanMarie: "I think it is not worth spending time on this issue" ... And yet, see my answer. ;)

Here's a fairly nifty interpretation ...
Define $p:=|PF|$, and write $e$ for the ellipse's eccentricity. We can locate points $P_0 (=P)$, $P_1 (=F)$, $P_2$, $P_3$, $\ldots$ on axis-line $PF$ such that $|P_kP_{k+1}|=pe^k$. Since $e<1$, we know the $P_k$ converge at a finite point; OP's observation is that this point is $A$, the ellipse's "far" vertex.
This diagram shows the situation ... and hints at more:

Let $Q_k$ on the ellipse be the head of the perpendicular to the axis-line at $P_k$. Note that $|PP_k|$ is the distance from $Q_k$ to the directrix; by the focus-directrix definition of the ellipse, and the geometrically-progressive nature of the segment lengths, we have that
$$|FQ_k| \;=\; e\,|P_0P_k| \;=\; e\cdot p\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} e^j \;=\; \left(p\sum_{j=0}^k e^j\right)-p \;=\;|P_0P_{k+1}|-|P_0P_1| \;=\;|FP_{k+1}| \tag{$\star$}$$
This says that we can follow a circular arc about $F$ from a given $Q$ to the "next" $P$. Iterating this process takes us from $Q_1$ (notably, an endpoint of a latus rectum of the ellipse) to the limit point of vertex $A$.
Even better:

We can start that process at any point $R$ on the major axis of the ellipse.

That is, we can travel up the perpendicular at $R$ to a point on the ellipse, then down a circular arc centered at $F$ to another point on the axis; then up and down to another point; and another; etc; always approaching $A$ in the limit.

Defining (signed) distance $r:=|FR|$, one can show that the distance from the directrix to the successive points has the form
$$p \left(1+e+e^2+\cdots+e^k\right) + r e^k$$
This phenomenon is illustrated very nicely with a parabola ($e=1$), which lacks the convergence property but shows that successive points are equally-spaced, so that the distance from directrix to a point is always $r$ plus an appropriate multiple of $p$.

(I'll note here that hyperbolas ($e>1$) with this process also generate geometrically-progressive distances, which obviously also lack convergence. And yet, the (directed) distance from the directrix to the "far" vertex is still $p/(1-e)$. Hmmm ...)
Anyway, as $k$ increases without bound in a proper ellipse ($e<1$), the second term becomes negligible, and the first term's geometric summation still approaches $p/(1-e)=|P_0A|$.
I'll stop typing now. :)

Indeed ! I am amazed, once more, by your answer...
